# Does posix write ensure file offset unchanged on failure?

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix, rocksdb, leveldb

I'm learning LevelDB and RocksDB and are confused by how they keep WAL data integrity without truncate.

What I found:

1. Log files are always seeked at block boundaries (which is 8 KiB). Guess that means there's no garbage between two blocks.
2. The log writer (and underlying WriteableFile) never truncates file on failure writes. It just continues write. Guess that means a failed write won't change the file offset so next write still locate at where it should be.

But from [Posix spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)  it says:

> This volume of POSIX.1-2017 does not specify the value of the file offset after an error is returned; there are too many cases. For programming errors, such as [EBADF], the concept is meaningless since no file is involved. For errors that are detected immediately, such as [EAGAIN], clearly the pointer should not change. After an interrupt or hardware error, however, an updated value would be very useful and is the behavior of many implementations.

So is this a unspecific behavior which should not rely on or actually ensured by practical systems and safe to use?

Comment: Databases often use direct IO, which gives them more control than the normal `write()` system call.

Comment: @Barmar DIO needs aligned writes and IMO not suitable for this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning LevelDB and RocksDB and are confused by how they keep WAL
> data integrity without truncate.

RocksDB first split the log file to be fixed-length "blocks"(which is 32KiB). The fixed-length blocks make it easy to verify the checksum of each block while reading.

And upon the fixed-length blocks, there are serialized "records". The length of each "record" could be stored across multiple "blocks". And the atomicity of each WriteBatch in rocksdb is ensured by we can read the full content of a "record", with blocks ensuring the checksum integrity.

If write failure happens, the next time we open the same log file for reading, the last incomplete write is ignored so that the incomplete WriteBatch that met I/O error is not committed.

> The log writer (and underlying WriteableFile) never truncates file on failure writes. It just continues write. Guess that means a failed write won't change the file offset so next write still locate at where it should be.

I think RocksDB won't reuse the same log file for writing if I/O error happened. (not sure yet)

I tried to truncate the log file when I/O error happened and reuse it next time program restarts. But it ends up with many corner case problems and I don't think it is a good practice.